# Is there an official maintained vscode snap available from microsoft on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

After reading the following [link](https://news.softpedia.com/news/you-can-now-install-microsoft-s-visual-studio-code-ide-as-a-snap-on-ubuntu-linux-515882.shtml), I searched the snap repo for an official snap.
But did only find what I assume is an *unofficial* snap for vscode.

```
$ snap find vscode
Name    Version            Developer      Notes    Summary
vscode  1.23.0-1525361119  flexiondotorg  classic  Code editing. Redefined.
```

I also did not see anything about any official snap on the official vscode site https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Looking through the **vscode** [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#asking-questions) I read the following so here I am.

> Have a question? Rather than opening an issue, please ask away on
>   Stack Overflow using the tag vscode.

---

Question!

Is there an official maintained **vscode** snap available from microsoft?

If the answer to the above is no. Does anybody know if there is one planned for the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first posted this question in the askubuntu community ([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037042/is-there-an-official-maintained-vscode-snap-available-from-microsoft-on-ubuntu-1)) and which now has an answer.

## Answer:

No.
A Visual Studio Code software engineer who's been working on the snap [said](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5458#issuecomment-388520029):

> I've had too much other work to focus on to take this to the finish line. One of the things that was really bugging me is that every time I went to get some work done on it I would run into another major issue that needed help from the snapcraft team like random crashes or things not working.

Click the link above to see what work needs to be done to get it working and help if you are able!

I'm a member of the snapcrafters GitHub organisation [where `flexiondotorg`'s snap is held](https://github.com/snapcrafters/vscode). The snapcrafters org is as close to official as unofficial can get. I have no commit access to the repositories, I think the three Snap Advocates (Canonical employees) have that (and sometimes other members who they trust to commit to certain snaps) and access to push `edge` snaps built from the GitHub repos to other channels including `stable`. `flexiondotorg` is Martin Wimpress, one of the Snap Advocates (and also, as it happens, the lead of Ubuntu MATE). I think you can trust our VS Code snap, although it would be better if Microsoft distributed it themselves, but they've got stuck, sad times :(